# Trouble matching login password with stored hashed password in database

Tags: php, mysql, hash, salt

I am new to PHP and MYSQL and am working on a registration/login form project to build up my knowledge but I am a bit stuck, so hope you can help.

I have a database on PHPMyAdmin and my registration form searches to see if the email address already exists if not to insert all the information into the database. This works fine. I also have a login form which searched for the email address and password to see if they matched any in the database, if so to log in. This worked fine.

My issue came when I started to learn about password salts/hashing. I can still register okay but when I try to login with details already in the database it doesn't seem to match the passwords up to allow me to log in.

register.php

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'db_connect.php';

// Stores the information submitted from the form via the $_POST variable 
// if the request method in the form is POST then execute the following code (read the                 submitted information - send the email  and redirect to the header location
// if it is NOT POST then it will skip this code block and show blank contact form
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    $fname = trim($_POST["fname"]);
    $lname = trim($_POST["lname"]);
    $cname = trim($_POST["cname"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $pass1 = trim($_POST["pass1"]);
    $pass2 = trim($_POST["pass2"]);

// VALIDATIONS


// All required fields must be entered
if ($fname == "" OR $lname == "" OR $email == "" OR $pass1 == "" OR $pass2 == "") {
    $error_message = "You must fill in all the required fields.";

}

// password must contain 6 characters min
if (strlen($pass1) < 6) {
       $error_message = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";

}
//passwords must match each other
if ($pass1 != $pass2) {
   $error_message = "Passwords do not match";
}


// hash and salt password - PASSWORD_DEFAULT uses the php default hashing algorithm - 
// cost is the expense used to generate the hash (higher the number the more secure but slower the page load)

$password_save = password_hash($pass1 . SALT , PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('cost' => 10 ));

// if there's not a previous error message run a database query to look if the email address entered matches any already in the database.
if (!isset ($error_message)){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM registration_tbl WHERE email = '".$email."'";
  $query_run = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  // if the query locates more than 0 (i.e 1+) records with matching email addresses then echo out the error
  // else insert all new form data in to the database and echo a success message      
  if (mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0) {
       $error_message = "Email Address ".$email." is already registered";
  } else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO registration_tbl (first_name,last_name,company_name,email,password,reg_datetime) VALUES ('".$fname."','".$lname."','".$cname."','".$email."','".$password_save."', NOW())";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
        echo "Registration Successful";
    }
}
```

login.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'db_connect.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$pass = trim($_POST["pass"]);

    // VALIDATIONS

// both fields must be entered to log in        
if($email == "" OR $pass == "") {
    $error_message = "Both fields must be completed ";
}

$hashandsalt = password_hash($pass . SALT, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('cost' => 10 ));

// if no error message is set - send a query to the database for all records in the registration_tbl where the email matches one in the database
// if the query returns less than 1 record (i.e no matches in the database) show error message
// else if found in the database save the login details to session variables and then
// redirect to the logged-in.php page   
if (!isset ($error_message)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM registration_tbl WHERE email ='".$email."'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query_run)<1 ){
        $error_message = "Your login details do not match, please double check and try again1";
    } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
        echo ($row['password']) ."<br>";
        echo $pass ."<br>";
        echo $hashandsalt;

            if (password_verify($pass, $hashandsalt)){
                $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['first_name'];
                $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['last_name'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['ID'];
                header("location: logged-in.php");
            } else {
                $error_message = "Your login details do not match, please double check and try again";
            }
        }
    }
}
}
?>

<div class="wrapper">

<?php
 if(!isset ($error_message)) {
    echo '<p>Please complete the log in details </p>';
    } else {
    echo $error_message;
 }
?>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="email"> Email Address </label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($email)) { echo htmlspecialchars($email); } ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="pass"> Password </label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

The results of the 3 echos I have in the login.php

```
echo ($row['password']) ."<br>";
```

This one will show the hashed password from the database

```
        echo $pass ."<br>";
```

This one will show whatever password is entered

```
        echo $hashandsalt;
```

This one shows a new hashed password which differs each time the page is refreshed

This is where my query is I am obviously missing something which is not allowing the password entered to match up to the already stored hashed password.

I have scoured the internet including number of stack overflow posts but I can't quite seem to figure out what I have done wrong. This is my first post so I hope I am posting enough information for you.

Any ideas guys?

p.s I know I need to add the mysqli_real_escape_string - this was my next job after figuring this one out :ve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify the password you need to check with the stored password-hash from the database. There is no need to call `password_hash()` in login.php.

login.php

```
if (password_verify($pass, $row['password']))
```

Also there is no need to add a salt before hashing, the function password_hash() will add it automatically.

register.php

```
$password_save = password_hash($pass1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('cost' => 10 ));
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.

I did as suggested, removed the . salt from the register.php $password_save and I amended the if statement in the login page as suggested above but it still generates my error of "your login details don't match, please try again".

Comment: @Grigson - Make sure that your database field for the password_hash can hold minimum 60 characters, and of course you should generate new users to test, the already stored hashes with the "salt" won't work.

Comment: The database field can hold up to 255 characters - and yep, just created a new user - again creates okay but when I try to log in it doesn't show me the error anymore it says "please complete the login details" as it does when the page is first seen

Comment: @Grigson - I cannot see this part of the code, where does it come from? Maybe it helps if you place an exit just after the header redirect `header(...); exit;` this you should do anyway, because otherwise the script continues to run.

Comment: I just added exit; after the header(..); and it now loads a blank page.Apart from the two echos - I have also just amended my original post within the 'login.php' section so you can see the rest of the code I have within it.

Comment: @Grigson - Ok now you have to remove all echos before the `header()` call, because the redirecting with `header()` only works if no output was generated before, not even a space before the `<?php` tag is allowed. Actually with error reporting on, you should get the "header already sent" warning.

Comment: ah-haaaa!! - Did not realise about the echos and the header() - Thank you so much it all appears to be working fantastically now, it really was confusing me so much, such a relief.

Comment: I have marked as correct answer but I'm afraid I don't have enough rep to be able to vote it up - But if I could have I would have :) Thanks again.